# Pass by reference in VBA does not work

Tags: ms-access, vba

i wanna test pass by reference and pass by value in access, but it doesn't work.

```
Sub passByRef(ByRef a As Integer)
   a = a + 1
End Sub
Sub passByVal(ByVal a As Integer)
   a = a + 1
End Sub

Private Sub cmdByRef()
   Dim i as Integer
   i = 10
   passByRef i
   MsgBox i
End Sub
Private Sub cmdByVal()
   Dim i as Integer
   i = 10
   passByVal i
   MsgBox i
End Sub
```

in the pass by ref it does not state that it is the pass by reference function. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maybe you should do this.

Private Sub cmdByRef()
   Dim i as Integer
   i = 10
   passByRef i
   MsgBox "Result of passByRef " + i
End Sub
Private Sub cmdByVal()
   Dim i as Integer
   i = 10
   passByVal i
   MsgBox "Result of passByVal " + i
End Sub
```